# How to change the action and method of a Wix Velo form?

Tags: forms, velo

I have a website on Wix.

Using the Wix classic editor, I have created a drag & drop form. The button is set to redirect to a URL after completion of the form.

How can I make the form redirect to another form (hosted on another website) and prefill it? The form on the other website is set up to accept the data input by the user, if the field names are correct, which they are.

The form on my Wix site does not appear to have an action or method set in the HTML.

Can I do this in dev mode with Velo?

Whilst I am familiar with HTML and CSS, JS is not something I have used much. Can I set the action and method via JS?

Many thanks in advance.

I have tried adding the desired URL as the button action after completion, however the data isn't being transferred. I believe the form needs the action setting to "url/form?" and method setting to GET.